# How to find a 2D coordinate field's corners in a 3D Coordinate field if I have 3x 3D points with 3x2D Points?

Tags: coordinate-systems, transformation, affine-geometry

In order to solve "[this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167786/mapping-a-touchinput-device-in-a-3d-world-for-vr)" problem, i have to transform my corner-points from a 2D Space to my 3D Space.

But my two coordinate fields are only defined by their relation to each other.
They have the same distance-vector's relations. (i guess)

Is this even solvable?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest transformation between the two coordinate systems, and the one I suspect you’ve got in mind, is an affine map. It’s convenient to work in homogeneous coordinates, which allows this map to be represented by a $4\times3$ matrix $M$. I’ll use lower-case letters for points in the 2-D $u$-$v$ coordinate system and upper-case for points in the 3-D coordinate system to avoid ambiguity.

The constraints provided by the three point pairs can be captured in the “bulk” matrix equation $$M \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf p_1&\mathbf p_2&\mathbf p_3\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf P_1&\mathbf P_2&\mathbf P_3\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ from which it immediately follows that $$M = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf P_1&\mathbf P_2&\mathbf P_3\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf p_1&\mathbf p_2&\mathbf p_3\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$ The inverse of the right-hand matrix exists as long as the three points are not colinear. (If they are, and the 3-D points are, too, there’s not a unique affine map, whereas if the 3-D points aren’t colinear, then there’s no affine map.) As a sanity check on your computation, the last row of $M$ should be $(0,0,1)$.†

The images of the corners of the 2-D unit square are then found by multiplying their homogeneous coordinate vectors by $M$, but the results will be simple combinations of the columns of $M$: $$(0,0) \mapsto M_3 \\ (1,0) \mapsto M_1+M_3 \\ (0,1) \mapsto M_2+M_3 \\ (1,1) \mapsto M_1+M_2+M_3.$$ You need to dehomogenize, of course, but if you’ve done this correctly, the last coordinate will always be $1$, so all you need to do to get the corresponding inhomogeneous Cartesian coordinates is to drop it.

† In fact, in practice you can drop the last row of $M$ so that you get dehomogenized coordinates directly when you multiply a homogeneous coordinate vector by $M$. If the last element of the homogeneous coordinate vector $\mathbf p$ is $1$, then so will be the last element of $M\mathbf p$, and dehomogenizing the result is a matter of dropping this $1$, as noted elsewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, im a beginner and I am also only a programmer and not a mathematician. So I have a few noob-questions: 1. As far as I can tell you renamed: 
P1.x to P1 , P1.y to P2, P1.z to P3? And P1.u and P1.v to p1 and p2... What do you use instead of p3 ? since we dont have a third coordinate from our 2d dimension uv

Comment: Do I fill it with Matrix.Identity values??

Comment: Nope. Each of the $p$’s is the entire 2- or 3-element coordinate vector of the point, written as a column vector per the usual mathematical convention. You’ll end up multiplying a $4\times3$ matrix by the inverse of a $3\times3$ matrix to compute $M$.

Comment: ohhh okay, that was my first mistake.

Now ... I got M

Next I need to Multiply the 3D VECTOR with the M matrix to get a 3D coordinate, right?

So i multiply... lets say I want to know where my 2D point: 0.1/0.7 in the 3d World is...

I multiply  Vector3( 0.1, 0.7, ?? ) with M..?
So.. there is the third digit missing.... right?

Comment: And how do I dehomogenize something?
I never dehomogenized anything in my life.... so... for stupid people.... dehomogenize means.... what?

Comment: ok- well i made it work. :-)

Comment: @OC_RaizW The homogeneous coordinates of a point have an “extra” component: the homogeneous coordinates corresponding to the ordinary $(x,y)$ are $(wx,wy,w)$, where $w$ can be any nonzero value, typically $1$ for convenience. To convert back into ordinary coordinates (“dehomogenize”), divide by $w$. That final $1$ is preserved, so to dehomogenize you simply drop it. If you’re going to be doing more with computer graphics in the future, you should take the time to learn about them, as they’re almost ubiquitous.